Declaring multiple sequential pointers/values in C
There must be a better way. Please redeem my soul.
tword_t registers[13] = {0};
tword_t *R1 = registers;
tword_t *R2 = registers + 1;
tword_t *R3 = registers + 2;
tword_t *R4 = registers + 3;
tword_t *R5 = registers + 4;
tword_t *R6 = registers + 5;
tword_t *R7 = registers + 6;
tword_t *R8 = registers + 7;
tword_t *R9 = registers + 8;
tword_t *R10 = registers + 9;
tword_t *R11 = registers + 10;
tword_t *R12 = registers + 11;
tword_t *R13 = registers + 12;

My small dum-dum bad no good brain can't come up with anything better than a for/while loop and that's obviously useless here.
I need them to be sequential, hence the array to force the addresses and pointers instead of regular old values - I know that
tword_t R1 = 0;
tword_t R2 = 0;
...

would most likely give them neighbouring addresses, but I'd rather not leave it to chance and the compiler's whims.
Also just in case someone points this out: yes, those +1, +2... are OK, the compiler multiplies it by the type's size. I found out when I tried to do +8, +16... and it didn't work.

Why do you need all those variables? Just use array indexes, registers[0], registers[1], etc.

If you really must have those, use a union?

enum registers { R1, R2, /* and so on... */, R13 }; Then you can use registers[R2] (for example) to access a specific register.

Your question is unclear. (a) The bulk of it seems to be asking about creating names for these objects, but mentioning “a for/while loop” seems to be asking about assigning values to make the pointers work. Clarify which question you are asking. (b) There are multiple ways to create objects that are consecutive in memory and to name those objects (as array elements, as structure members, as array elements indexed by enum constants…), but the only way to make the names R1, R2, … is to define those as macros. But you ask for “better”. What does that mean?

Well, there is one other way to make the names be R1, R2,… without using macros. Declare them as extern tword_t R1, R2,…; and use assembly language to define them consecutively in memory. Is that “better”?

tword_t *Ri = &register[i];, for each index i perhaps?

What's your actual goal here?  Why do you need the registers array and also need pointers to each tword_t?  This will help us give you proper advice.

@Niloct that is basically what the shown code does.

"the compiler multiplies it" well yes, that is how pointer arithmetics work. Everything else would be a surprise.

Why don't you show us how you want to use the variables you define? You mention that you are thinking of a loop; an array is the proper data structure for loops, single variables are, by contrast, not. That's often the first step when somebody learns to code: Use an array instead of single variables, and loop over it instead of repeating the same code n times for each single variable.

@Someprogrammerdude I completely forgot about enums, they're what I need. Thanks!

The use of an array guarantees that the values will be sequential and properly aligned, so there is nothing you can improve on that.
If we really want to find something to improve, then there is a couple of things perhaps worth considering.  (Hardly.)

Note: I have not actually tried this, so keep in mind that it may not necessarily compile without a bit of tweaking:
#define DEFR(N) tword_t* const R#N = registers + N - 1
DEFR(1);
DEFR(2);
DEFR(3);
DEFR(4);
DEFR(5);
DEFR(6);
DEFR(7);
DEFR(8);
DEFR(9);
DEFR(10);
DEFR(11);
DEFR(12);
DEFR(13);

Is it useful? Hardly.
(But note that const is useful; you forgot that one.)

What might bring some advantage is the following:
The registers do not have to be pointers.  So, you can do something like this:
#define R1 registers[0]
#define R2 registers[1]
#define R3 registers[2]
#define R4 registers[3]
#define R5 registers[4]
#define R6 registers[5]
#define R7 registers[6]
#define R8 registers[7]
#define R9 registers[8]
#define R10 registers[9]
#define R11 registers[10]
#define R12 registers[11]

So, in order to access the value of a register, you do not first have to go obtain a pointer, and then dereference that pointer to access the value pointed by it; you can just directly access the value.  It is more optimal, and it also looks better in source code; what would you rather type? R1 = 42; or *R1 = 42;?

That's almost it, but I'm worried making it a global variable will decrease performance

If you're trying to treat them as registers, I'd prefer macro approach as in my past pre-silicon simulator project. The loop thru assignment is only for the init which macro has already done, and for the rest of time, it is rarely or almost never to assign all of them with a loop. Furthermore, the same macro can also be used for another similar group of registers in the project.
#define DECLARE_REG_POINTERS(type, base, name, cnt) \
    type base[cnt]; type *name##1=base, *name##2=base+1, \
    *name##3=base+2, *name##4=base+3, *name##5=base+4, \
    *name##6=base+5, *name##7=base+6, *name##8=base+7, \
    *name##9=base+8, *name##10=base+9, *name##11=base+10, \
    *name##12=base+11, *name##cnt=base+(cnt-1)

To use it:
DECLARE_REG_POINTERS(tword_t, registers_r, R, 13);

